# about fancy indexing in numpy, like `a[b]` or `a[np.array(b)]`, b is a list. the result is different

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

there is someting confusing me:

```py
a = np.array([7,8,9,10])
b=[[3,1],[1,2]]
print(a[b])
"""
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
"""
```

but transform b=[[3,1],[1,2]] to:

```py
b=np.array([[3,1],[1,2]])
print(a[b])
"""
array([[10, 8],
       [ 8, 9]])
"""
```

okay, someone know why b must be a ndarray instead of list?
thanks.

Comment: Because `list` only supports `int` and slice indexing. Ndarrays have overridden this behavior to accept lists and ndarrays, as well.

Comment: I highly recommend reading how numpy interprets integer-array indices for ndarrays via their [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

Comment: This is a historical legacy that developers are trying to fix. The list should be treated like the array, but in the past some lists where treated like tuples.

Answer (score 1):

In a new enough numpy version we get a warning along with the error:

```
In [113]: a = np.array([7,8,9,10])
     ...: b=[[3,1],[1,2]]
In [114]: a[b]
<ipython-input-114-48d1ef76a37c>:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; 
use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, 
which will result either in an error or a different result.
  a[b]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-114-48d1ef76a37c>", line 1, in <module>
    a[b]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

So historically some lists of lists were interpreted as:

```
In [115]: a[tuple(b)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-115-b78d8d2bd7a8>", line 1, in <module>
    a[tuple(b)]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

The desired array interpretation:

```
In [116]: a[np.array(b)]
Out[116]: 
array([[10,  8],
       [ 8,  9]])
```